# Subfolder config — 2 apps in 1 domain

Tags: nginx

There are 2 single page apps on a server (`App-One` and `App-Two`).

To access `App-One` there is the domain `www.app-one.com`. `App-Two` is reachable within the same domain in a subfolder: `www.app-one.com/app-two`.

Both apps are in the `/var/www/` folder on the server:

- Folder `/var/www/www.app-one.com` for `App-One`
- Folder `/var/www/app-two` for `App-Two`

## The problem

If I enter `www.app-one.com/app-two` in the browser, it redirects to `www.app-one.com`.

If I enter `www.app-one.com/app-two/index.html` everything works.

## The nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.app-one.com app-one.com;

    # www rewrite
    if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.app-one.com permanent;
    }

    # Logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.app-one.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.app-one.com_error.log;

    # App-One
    index index.html;
    root /var/www/www.app-one.com;

    # App-One
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    # App-Two
    location /app-two {
        alias /var/www/app-two;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

## What I tried

A lot of location filters (`=`, `~`, ...) and using `root` instead of `alias` in the app-two location. But if I do that, the relative links to the assets of `App-Two` are pointing to the wrong URL.

What is wrong in this config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try_files` statements are incorrect. The `try_files` statement should end with either a default URI or an error code, not both. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

In the case of *app-one* the statement should look like:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

In the case of *app-two*, the default action needs to be the full URI, and not just the filename:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /app-two/index.html;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to let you know. It also works without the full URI for _app-two_ (`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`). This is because of the `alias`, right?

Comment: That's because it hasn't reached the final element. The matching directory name uses your `index` directive to find `/app-two/index.html`. But if you want something like `/app-two/foo` to find the correct `index.html`, you will need to specify it's URI.